# Get the first date of week DATE object for the user set 'first day of week' value

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a calendar application where the user can choose from  a dropdown 2 values:

**sunday** and **monday**

as the first day of week.

Given that the user set as **first day of week**: '`monday`' (dayIndex 1)

AND the current date is `sunday 11th january 2015` (dayIndex 0)

From where do I know that the FirstDateOfWeek is the

--> `monday 12th january 2015`

( where then the '`sunday 18th january 2015`' would be the last date of the week)

AND not the

--> `monday 5th january 2015`

(where then the `sunday 11th january 2015` would be the last date of the week)

Comment: Wouldn't, with weeks starting on monday, the first day of the week ending with sunday jan 11  be *monday jan 5* (year = 2015)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first day of the week is Sunday, subtract the day number from the date to get the first Sunday of that week. If Monday is the first day, do Date - ((dayNumber || 7) - 1). In a function:

```
/**
 * Given a Date, return a new Date object for the first
 * day of the week.
 * @param {Date} date - date object
 * @param {boolean} mon - true if week starts on Monday, otherwise starts on Sunday
*/
function getFirstDayOfWeek(date, mon) {

  // copy date object
  date = new Date(+date);

  if (mon) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - (date.getDay() || 7) + 1);

  } else {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay());
  }
  return date;
}

// Sun 11 Jan 2015
var date = new Date(2015, 0, 11)

console.log(getFirstDayOfWeek(date));       // Sun 11 Jan 2015
console.log(getFirstDayOfWeek(date, true)); // Mon 05 Jan 2015
```

So you just need to store the user's choice of which day of the week they want to start on, then pass either true (if it's Monday) or false (if it's Sunday).

Comment: Thanks for the code, my unit tests are green now to my expectations :-)